# Azures Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) Build & Release process fetches more projects than just the project I am wanting to build

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

My VSTS Repository contains 50+ Visual Studio projects of Azure Web Apps and I was requested to get an automated build and release process in place for one of them. I went thru and selected a Visual Studio template and on the build solution I selected only the one project I wanted to do a build and release on but when I queue the build to run it starts doing a get latest on every project in the repository. This is unacceptable because it would take hours to get latest on all the projects just to compile and publish one website.  This makes no sense to me. Is there a way to limit what the build does a get latest on?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the repository type you're using. In case you're using TFVC, you can go to the Repositories tab and configure your workspace mappings to match exactly what you need for your project.

If you're using Git, then you're out of luck, the way git repositories are synced, the whole repository is always fetched when a build is initiated.

If you're using your own build agent, you can configure it to retain the sources directory, in which case only the differences are synced when a build runs.